# How to deal with long legend labels when using multiple columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

It is necessary that the legend element can occupy several columns so that the legend does not stretch. It should work at any `ncol` value.

[image: Problem]

If you increase the length of the word "Some Line", then the right column will go beyond the picture at some point. I showed the square where I would like to see the legend of the right.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y1 = [4, 6, 8, 2, 10]
y2 = [5, 1, 9, 3, 7]
plt.plot(x, y1, 'b-', label='Line 1')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Line 2', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Line 3', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Some Liiiiiiiiiiine', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Line 5', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Line 6', linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x, y2, 'r--', label='Line 7', linewidth=2)

plt.xlim(0, 6)
plt.ylim(0, 12)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Problem with ncol')

ax.legend(fontsize=12, loc='lower center', ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you explain the problem better? The legend doesn't look like it's wrong...

Comment: An alternative you could try would be `label='Some\nLiiiiiiiiiiine'`. It's not exactly what you are asking, but woulf be more compact as the original.

Comment: @Joao_PS, If you increase the length of the word "Some Line", then the right column will go beyond the picture at some point.I showed the square where I would like to see the legend of the right.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney, One of the solutions is to set the values of ncol=1, so I clarified about ncol.

Comment: @JohanC, Thanks for the alternative solution! (it doesn't fully answer my question)

Comment: I suggest splitting it into two legends... One legend with smaller labels and one with larger labels. Search for "Multiple legends on the same Axes" here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html